# Opening persistent shell in Python

Tags: python, shell

I need to open a "persistent shell" from within Python.

In that shell I need to start a process which I need to communicate with in future separate calls from my Python code. In a sense, I need a "shell handle" much like a file handle that I can talk to and any running process will keep running as long as the shell is open.

So, I need something like this:

```
s = open_shell() <-- handle to shell is now "s"
s.call(run_some_process_in_the_shell())
```

... do other things in Python; but the process keeps running in shell "s" ...

```
s.call(interact_with_running_process())
```

.. be even more productive ...

```
s.call(interact_with_running_process_again())
```

*etc.*

My current understanding, which could be wrong, is that, sure the process "run_some_process_in_the_shell()" can be called, but it will exit immediately after. That is, the process will not be running in "s" by the time I get back to it later.

I hope this makes sense, thanks.

Comment: I'd read up on subprocess here:https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

there are ways to interact with live processes

Comment: This is what I ended up doing:

Install pexpect:

    pip install pexpect

Then "import pexpect" and:

    s = pexpect.spawn("/bin/bash")
    s.sendline(run_some_process_in_the_shell())

and that was it. Now, I also needed to check that a particular process was running. To check that, I did:
    
    s.sendline("ps")
    s.expect(name_of_process_I_expect_to_be_running)
    print s.after <--- prints name of process that is running (sanity check)

Comment: and thanks for looking into it @deweyredman.
I am still interested in other ways to do this so if subprocess works I am happy to hear about it :)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing:

Install pexpect: `pip install pexpect`

Then "import pexpect" and:

```
s = pexpect.spawn("/bin/bash")
s.sendline(run_some_process_in_the_shell())
```

and that was it.

Now, I also needed to check that a particular process was running. To check that, I did:

```
s.sendline("ps")
s.expect(name_of_process_I_expect_to_be_running)
print s.after <--- prints name of process that is running (sanity check)
```

–  denvar